# Eclipse for Java EE não inicia

Tags: java, eclipse

Meu Eclipse para Java EE não inicia, e dá um erro de primeira linha:

> java was started but not returned exit code=13

Sistema operacional de 64 bits (x64).

Comment: Instalou o JDK ?

Comment: Sim. java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Tenta executar como administrador.

Comment: É windows? a variável de ambiente foi criada?

Comment: Sim, windows 7. dá o mesmo resultado quando executado em administrador.

Comment: Já tentou alguma dessas alternativas: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11461607/1342547

Comment: sim. eu tinha pego esse artigo para ver, mas não tive resultado.

Answer (score 6):

O problema é que você está tentando iniciar uma versão do Eclipse de 64 bits com uma versão do Java de 32 bits. Você pode baixá-lo [Java SE Development](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comece Eclipse com uma JVM de 64 bits e o problema sumir.

Comment: Obrigado, está funcionando.

Comment: @user12096 que bom ter ajudado você, você pode marcar minha resposta, ao ter solucionado o seu problema através dela.