# Erro ao tentar executar Eclipse: Java was started but return exit code =13. A PATH ESTÁ CORRETA

Tags: eclipse, jdk

Apaguei versões anteriores ao Java 8  e agora o eclipse não quer rodar, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> " Java was started but return exit code =13.":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem um tópico semelhante: já fiz o que dizia a solução do tópico: [Erro ao tentar executar Eclipse: Java was started but return exit code =13](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39207/50715)

Ou seja:
Eu já instalei de novo a JDK 1.7 e coloquei o caminho para ela na variável de ambiente `"Path": C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin`

E o erro continua o mesmo.

O que eu posso fazer pra consertar?

Comment: Abrindo o seu terminal de comandos, `java -version` retorna o quê? E `which java`? E `where java`? (eu não lembro se no Windows é `where` ou `which`, mas se você estiver usando `bash` a resposta correta é a contrária da resposta do Windows, então botei as duas opções)

Comment: Aparentemente a VM apontada pelo argumento `-vm` que está no caminho `.../Oracle/Java/javapath` não é a versão 7 da JVM

Comment: Hmmm, o java -version retorna a versão 1.8....

Comment: estranho, pensei que esses argumentos que pedem pelo Java 7 fosse requerimento mínimo...

Comment: Mas como eu altero a VM apontada pelo -vm?

Comment: No diretório onde está instalado o eclipse, tem um arquivo chamado `eclipse.ini`. É nesse rapaz que você altera. Recomendo antes guardar um backup dele, para só depois alterar e por a path desejada.

Comment: Parece que seu eclipse é 64 bits. Por que instalou o Java 32 bits? [Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34238/64969) relata o mesmo erro e a resposta foi por todo mundo no mesmo esquema de 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se a versão do seu eclipse é a mesma do JDK que você instalou, 64bits ou 32bits, veja a versão no *prompt* com o `java -version`.

Verifique se as variáveis de ambiente estão configuradas corretamente, executando o `javac` no *prompt*

Caso esteja no windows 10, configurar as variáveis de ambiente é um pouco diferente, se for o caso, siga os passos:

```
1.Em Pesquisar, procure e selecione: Sistema (Painel de Controle)
2.Clique no link Configurações avançadas do sistema.
3.Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente. Na seção Variáveis do Sistema, localize a variável de ambiente PATH e selecione-a. Clique em Editar. Se a variável de ambiente PATH não existir, clique em Novo.
4.Na janela Editar Variável de Sistema (ou Nova Variável de Sistema), especifique o valor da variável de ambiente PATH. Clique em OK. Feche todas as janelas restantes clicando em OK.
5.Reabra a janela Prompt de comando e execute o código Java.
```

Fonte [Configuração das variáveis PATH](https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: Eu fiz tudo isso. Só que o problema é que aparece a version 1.8 quando eu dou o comendo java -version

Comment: Pode ser que tenha ficado falhas no registro do Windows, aqui tem um "reparador" que tenta ajustar os registros - https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/manual_regedit.xml

Answer (score 0):

Eu precisei remover as versões 1.7 x86 e 1.8 x86 do jdk instaladas, com este programa do windows: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed , e então baixei a jdk 1.7 64 bits (x64), o que resolveu meu problema.